# Equivalent of set -o pipefail in Python?

Tags: python, bash, shell, pipe

I have a handful of Python scripts each of which make heavy use of sorting, uniq-ing, counting, gzipping and gunzipping, and awking.  As a first run through the code I've used `subprocess.call` with (yes I know of the security risks that's why I said it is a first pass) `shell=True`.  I have a little helper function:

```
def do(command):
    start = datetime.now()
    return_code = call(command, shell=True)
    print 'Completed in', str(datetime.now() - start), 'ms, return code =', return_code
    if return_code != 0:
        print 'Failure: aborting with return code %d' % return_code
        sys.exit(return_code)
```

Scripts make use of this helper as in the following snippets:

```
do('gunzip -c %s | %s | sort -u | %s > %s' % (input, parse, flatten, output))
do("gunzip -c %s | grep 'en$' | cut -f1,2,4 -d\|| %s > %s" % (input, parse, output))
do('cat %s | %s | gzip -c > %s' % (input, dedupe, output))
do("awk -F ' ' '{print $%d,$%d}' %s | sort -u | %s | gzip -c > %s" % params)
do('gunzip -c %s | %s | gzip -c > %s' % (input, parse, output))
do('gunzip -c %s | %s > %s' % (input, parse, collection))
do('%s < %s >> %s' % (parse, supplement, collection))
do('cat %s %s | sort -k 2 | %s | gzip -c > %s' % (source,other_source,match,output)
```

And there are many more like these, some with even longer pipelines.

One issue I notice is that when a command early in a pipeline fails, the whole command will still succeed with exit status 0.  In bash I fix this with

```
set -o pipefail
```

but I do not see how this can be done in Python.  I suppose I could put in an explicit call to bash but that seems wrong.  Is it?

In lieu of an answer to that specific question, I'd love to hear alternatives to implementing this kind of code in pure Python without resorting to `shell=True`.  But when I attempt to use `Popen` and `stdout=PIPE` the code size blows up.  There is something nice about writing pipelines on one line as a string, but if anyone knows an elegant multiline "proper and secure" way to do this in Python I would love to hear it!

An aside: none of these scripts ever take user input; they run batch jobs on a machine with a known shell which is why I actually ventured into the evil `shell=True` just to see how things would look.  And they do look pretty easy to read and the code seems *so* concise!  How does one remove the `shell=True` and run these long pipelines in raw Python while still getting the advantages of aborting the process if an early component fails?

Comment: Why not create a single bash script that does what you want, and call that script from Python? Then you control the whole pipeline thing better.

Comment: Or better yet, either just make a pure Bash script, or convert all the shell external calls to native Python

Comment: Ah, the calls to `do` are only part of much larger Python scripts.  There's too much logic in them (around the subprocess calls) to use bash, which is great for the pipelines but poor when dealing with arrays and conditional logic.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can set the `pipefail` in the calls to system:

```
def do(command):
  start = datetime.now()
  return_code = call([ '/bin/bash', '-c', 'set -o pipefail; ' + command ])
  ...
```

Or, as @RayToal pointed out in a comment, use the `-o` option of the shell to set this flag: `call([ '/bin/bash', '-o', 'pipefail', '-c', command ])`.

Comment: Thanks, nice. I ended up using `call([ '/bin/bash', '-o', 'pipefail', '-c', command ])`.

Comment: The idea was based completely on your answer, though. :)  I had never thought about calling bash.  It's obvious now.

Comment: This answer totally defeats the safety provided by shell=False. I would rather use shell=True in this case.

Comment: @DavidRissatoCruz Yeah, well, the OP explicitly asked about executing pipes provided as strings.  You _need_ a shell for this, either the implicit one you get using `shell=True` or the explicit one you get with my answer.  In both cases you will execute a string, so you need to _trust_ that string.  But I don't see how `shell=True` could help here unless you mean that it makes the trust issue more obvious.

Comment: I never meant saying your solution doesn't work, please don't take it this way. However he asked "alternatives to implementing this kind of code in pure Python without resorting to shell=True" ... "proper and secure way", and my point is that calling `bash -c` is as unsafe as using `shell=True`. From the security perspective, both solutions are exactly the same.

Comment: @DavidRissatoCruz You are right.  The problem is the "wash me but don't make me wet" kind.  PO states that pipes given as strings are kind of "nice" but on the other hand wants a "secure" solution and that without resorting to "shell=True".  All three are not achievable in one solution at the same time, IMHO.  But one can go the way to say, well, fixed strings, as long as I provide them myself completely, are not really insecure.  They only become insecure if they contain parts provided by the input.  The only other option would be to let go of strings completely for specifying the pipes.