# Pipeline is not failing when fail occurs inside python script

Tags: python, ios, continuous-integration, gitlab

So - I am writing a script for running iOS tests based on changes in project (not important to topic probably).

Within the script, there is a command, which will run the tests:

`cmd = "xcodebuild -workspace xxx.xcworkspace -scheme xxx -destination 'platform=iOS Simulator,name={0},OS=latest' -configuration Debug -derivedDataPath {1} test-without-building {2} -parallel-testing-enabled NO -enableCodeCoverage YES | xcpretty".format(os.environ['TEST_SIMULATOR_NAME'], os.environ['PWD'], result)`

and is executed like this:

`do(cmd)`

The `do()` method definition is ([source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21742587/equivalent-of-set-o-pipefail-in-python)):

```
def do(command):
  return_code = call([ '/bin/bash', '-c', 'set -o pipefail; ' + command ])
```

Gitlab job settings:

```
manualUiTestsBasedOnChanges:
  stage: uiTests
  only: ...some conditions...
  before_script: 
    - set -o pipefail
  script:
    - ../scripts/ci/run_UI_tests_based_on_changes.py
```

The problem with this is, that if a fail occurs within this script, it won't fail the job, even when `set -o pipefail` is set in before script AND in in the `do()` method. Visible on image below.

**Any ideas why it's behaving like this?**

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, the only working solution, I found is to send the string with command back to gitlab's shell and execute it there. 
Like this:

**In Python:**

```
cmd = "
xcodebuild 
   -workspace xxx.xcworkspace 
   -scheme xxx 
   -destination 'platform=iOS Simulator,name={0},OS=latest' 
   -configuration Debug 
   -derivedDataPath {1} test-without-building {2} 
   -parallel-testing-enabled NO 
   -enableCodeCoverage YES | xcpretty"
.format(os.environ['TEST_SIMULATOR_NAME'], os.environ['PWD'], result)

print(cmd)
```

**YAML:**

```
manualUiTestsBasedOnChanges:
  stage: uiTests
  only: ...some conditions...
  before_script: 
    - set -o pipefail
  script:
    - result=`../scripts/ci/run_UI_tests_based_on_changes.py`
    - eval "$result"
```